# Can CloudFormation deploy to the default subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm working with CloudFormation trying to deploy an EC2 and an RDS into security groups, with the EC2 SG as a WebDMZ group and the RDS SG only open to traffic from the EC2 group.

The security groups are working correctly, but the EC2 and RDS instances both give me the same error that they can't find the security group in VPC XYZ123, where XYZ123 is the ID of the default VPC--the only VPC, and I've verified that my security groups are indeed in that VPC.

I tried the code for my EC2 in another template and it worked, but only if I specifically assigned it to a public subnet.

This code is academic, not for production.  Can't I just have my assets deploy to a default or random subnet?  Aren't Security Groups at the instance level, so as long as it's the correct VPC it should be fine?  What am I missing?

```
Resources:
  04WebDMZ:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: Open to HTTP, HTTPS and SSH on all ports
      GroupName: 04WebDMZ
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: 04WebDMZ
  04DatabaseSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: Open to 04WebDMZ
      GroupName: 04DatabaseSG
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          SourceSecurityGroupName: 
            Ref: 04WebDMZ
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: 04DatabaseSG
  04PublicEC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-047a51fa27710816e
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: my_key_pair
      NetworkInterfaces: 
      - AssociatePublicIpAddress: True
        DeviceIndex: 0
        DeleteOnTermination: True

      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 04PublicEC2
      UserData:
        !Base64 |
        #!/bin/bash
        yum install httpd php php-mysql -y
        cd /var/www/html
        wget https://wordpress.org/wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz
        tar -xzf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz
        cp -r wordpress/* /var/www/html/
        rm -rf wordpress
        rm -rf wordpress-5.1.1.tar.gz
        chmod -R 755 wp-content
        chown -R apache:apache wp-content
        service httpd start
        chkconfig httpd on
  04RDS:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBSecurityGroups:
      - Ref: 04DatabaseSG
      AllocatedStorage: '5'
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.small
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: admin
      MasterUserPassword: admin
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 04RDS
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
```

Screenshot of the error:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkKKk.jpg

Comment: The VPC docs say "When you launch an EC2 instance without specifying a subnet, it's automatically launched into a default subnet in your default VPC." Not 100% sure this extends to CloudFormation launching EC2, but presume so. What error do you get from CloudFormation? If you simply launch EC2 from the awscli without specifying any subnet, does it launch correctly in one of your default VPC's public subnets?

Comment: Right--so I expected it to just go into the default subnet, which would have been fine.  The error is "The security group '04webdmz' does not exist in VPC 'vpc-99e639e4'" which is a dirty lie.

Comment: Yes, launching the standalone EC2 (removing the SG reference) works just fine, into the default VPC in a random subnet.

Comment: There is no such a thing like a "default subnet". Your VPC does not have any subnets. There is only "default VPC", but you are creating your own custom one.

Comment: @Marcin Maybe I was mistaken that the subnets in the VPC were default, but either way there are six subnets in there.  I don't remember creating them, but it's possible.  The docs suggest it should put the resource in a random subnet.

Comment: And the docs are titled "Default VPC and default subnet" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html

Comment: Ah sorry I see your point now.  This is due to cut-and-pasting from the wrong part of my debugging.  My original code did not create a VPC, and I've updated the question.